# no matching function for call to 'myStud::myStud(int, const char [5], int, int, int)'

Tags: c++

I am a beginner for C++ 
and I have some trouble with my final exam,
I have checked for several times and this error keeps showing up while I am trying to run the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class myStud 
{
private:
    int id;
    char name[10];
    int chin;
    int eng;
    int math;

public:
    myStud (int x1,char y1[]) {
        id = x1;
        *name  = *y1;
        cout << "called"<<endl; 
    }

    void setscore(int x,int y, int z) {
        chin=x;
        eng=y;
        math=z;
    }

    double getave(){
        double ave;
        ave =(chin+eng+math/3);
        cout<< "average: " << ave << endl;
    }

    void showdata(){
        cout <<"student"; 
        cout << "id:" <<  id << " ";
        cout << "name" <<  name<< " ";
        cout << "chin" <<  chin<< " "; 
        cout << "eng" <<  eng<< " "; 
        cout << "math" <<  math<< " "; 
    }   
};

int main (){

    myStud S1(301, "John", 80, 60, 75);

    S1.showdata ();
    S1.getave();

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

And here is the bug

> [Error] no matching function for call to 'myStud::myStud(int, const
>   char [5], int, int, int)'

I have chnaged my constructor's signature

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class myStud  {
private:
    int id;
    char name[10];
    int chin;
    int eng;
    int math;

public:
    myStud (int x1, char y1[], int c, int e,int m) {
        id = x1;
        *name = *y1;
        chin=c;
        eng=e;
        math=m; 
        cout << "建構元呼叫"<<endl; 
    }

    void setscore(int x,int y, int z) {
        chin=x;
        eng=y;
        math=z;
    }

    double getave() {
        double ave;
        ave =(chin+eng+math)/3;
        cout<< "average: " << ave << endl;
    }

    void showdata() {
        cout <<"studentinfo: "; 
        cout << "id:" <<  id << " ";
        cout << "name" <<  name<< " ";
        cout << "chin" <<  chin<< " "; 
        cout << "eng" <<  eng<< " "; 
        cout << "math" <<  math<< " "; 
    }   
};

int main () {

    myStud S1(301, "John", 80, 60, 75);

    S1.showdata ();
    S1.getave();

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

And now there seems like having some trouble from the output

```
studentinfo: id:301 nameJ chin80 eng60 math75 average: 71
```

The name didn't show out completely

Comment: The only constructor you've declared for `myStud` is `myStud(int x1,char y1[])`

Comment: `*name  = *y1;` is a logical error. Things will go more easily if you use `std::string` instead of char arrays

Comment: But our teacher insist to use char

Comment: Then you should look through your course material (or google) to find how you copy an entire string when its defined as a character array.

Answer (score 0):

You're constructing S1 like this:

```
myStud S1(301, "John", 80, 60, 75);
```

But your constructor's signature is this:

```
 myStud (int x1,char y1[])
```

It looks like you need to change it to something like this:

```
 myStud S1(301, "John");
```

You probably also want to call `setscore()` at some point - otherwise all your data is uninitialized (and the result of `getave()` will be garbage).

---

Per your updates/new questions:

1. If you want `chin 80` instead of `chin80`, then it's up to *YOU* to add spaces.

   EXAMPLE: `cout << "name " <<  name << " ";`
2. C++ [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) is different from C-style `char string[]` strings.  In particular, you must use special C functions like [strncpy()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy a string, and [strcmp()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) to compare C-style strings.

   EXAMPLE: `strncpy(name, y1, 10);`
3. Indentation matters.  There are different styles; I happen to like the Google Style Guidelines:

   https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html

'Hope that helps!

Comment: I have do what you told me to do but now the problem becomes  the output if my code is  studentid:301 nameJ chin80 eng60 math75 average: 71    It's seems like the name has come trouble.